# Retrieve some info based on the apk signature

Tags: android, licensing

I'm trying to implement a version invalidation system for server-based apps. With the following model:

In some petitions to the server the client add a keyword and if that password isn't in a white list the server responds with an error, and the applications shows a message warning that a Market update is required (typically because its a hacked version or is a password that was used for a legit version but has been blacklisted because a cracked version is using the same code).
For generating that password I'd like a  key recovered in run time that identify the compiled version (that way if the apk is recompiled it won't work)

Initially I considered to use the apk signature retrieved by a code like this:

```
public static int getSignature() {
    try {
        Signature sigs[] = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures;
        return sigs[0].hashCode();
    } catch (NameNotFoundException ignore) {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But is is pretty stupid since the hacker can retrieve the signature of my apk (installing it in a device and running a program with the code above (using my.apk.package name instead of getPackageName() )

And then modify the getSignature() method to return a faked code instead of the real signature.

So my question is if there is some kind of info (signature dependent or similar) but not easily accessible from outside the app, that way if the code is recompiled with another signature that value is changed and can't be so easily to guess

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If your app is a paid one, you may want to have a look at:
http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html

This may be a long read and some work, but hey, that's the price for security.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're out of luck since *anything* inside your .apk can be read by almost everyone, esp. on rooted devices.

You should definitely consider obfuscation of your app, e.g. using ProGuard.